# Is there a way to inspect all queries that are submitted to apache iceberg?

Tags: apache-iceberg

I am new to [Apache iceberg](https://iceberg.apache.org/).  I would like to know if there is a way I can inspect the queries that are submitted to iceberg.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, iceberg is not a service and you can't submit tasks to it.

But if you just want to get all the events that try to query the iceberg table, you can create a listener to listen for all the events that take place in iceberg, including scanning of course.
You can take a look at the `org.apache.iceberg.events` package under `iceberg-api` module.
Hope it will help you.